# Regular functions, their zeros and irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

By $X$ we denote some affine variety embedded in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Suppose $\phi\in \mathbb{k}[X]$ divides zero, i.e. there is $\psi\in\mathbb{k}[X]$ such that $\phi\psi=0$. Furthermore, it means that $X$ is a union $V(\psi)\cup V(\phi)$. If $X_i$ is an irreducible component then $X_i\subset V(\phi)$ or $X_i\subset V(\psi)$. There exists $i$ such that $X_i\subset V(\phi)$. It is easy to see that $\phi|_{X_i}=0$. So, we have just proved that each zero divisor in $\mathbb{K}[X]$ is zero on some irreducible component.
Could you tell me if the converse true, namely, is it true that the regular function wich is zero on some irreducible component divides zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true (assuming $X$ is not irreducible, of course). Let $\phi\in\mathbb{k}[X]$ that is zero on some irreducible component $X_i$ of $X$ and let $Y_1,\ldots, Y_r$ be the other irreducible components of $X$. Since $Y:=Y_1\cup\cdots\cup Y_r$ is closed, there is a regular function $\psi$ such that $\psi|_Y=0$ and $\psi(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\in X_i\backslash Y$. This means that $\psi\phi=0$.